# Problem where date and time can not be in together in one row

Tags: arrays, reactjs, api, mapping

So I have this problem where the date and time can not be in one row. I tried everything but in the end, I failed to do so. I have two different arrays which are data and hari. Data will store the time value and hari will store the date value. The date array will display only a unique or distinct value. So what I get from this code is shown in the first picture and what I wanted is shown in picture two. Hence, anyone who can help pls help me solve my problem. Below is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import timestamp from "unix-timestamp";
import DateObject from "react-date-object";

var convertTime = require("convert-time");

var date = new DateObject();
date._format = "MMM DD YYYY";

export const Result = (code) => {
  const [output, setOutput] = useState([]);
  const [time, setTime] = useState([]);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [hari, setHari] = useState([]);

  var requestOptions = {
    method: "GET",
    redirect: "follow",
  };
  async function getWaktuSolat() {
    await fetch("https://mpt.i906.my/api/prayer/" + code.code, requestOptions)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result.data);
        setOutput(result.data);
        setTime(result.data.times);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
  }
  let i = 0;

  function outputList() {
    data.length = 0;
    hari.length = 0;
    for (let x = 0; x < time.length; x++) {
      for (let z = 0; z < 6; z++) {
        let j = timestamp.toDate(time[x][z]);
        data.push(j.toString().slice(15, 21));
        date.parse(j.toString().slice(4, 15));
        hari.push(date.format("DD/MM/YYYY"));
      }
    }
  }
  outputList();

  const renderTable = (data) => {
    const rows = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 6) {
      rows.push(<tr key={i}>{renderRow(data.slice(i, i + 6))}</tr>);
    }
    return rows;
  };
  
  const renderRow = (row) => {
    return row.map((element) => <td key={element}>{element}</td>);
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(code.code);
    getWaktuSolat();
    setData([]);
  }, [code.code]);
  const unique = (value, index, self) => {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
  };
  const renderHari = (uniqueHari) => {
    return uniqueHari.map((item) => <td key={item}>{item}</td>);
  };

  const uniqueHari = hari.filter(unique);

  return (
    <div className="Result">
      <h1>{output.place}</h1>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Hari</th>
            <th>Subuh</th>
            <th>Syuruk</th>
            <th>Zuhur</th>
            <th>Asar</th>
            <th>Maghrib</th>
            <th>Isyak</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody> 
        {uniqueHari.map((element, index) => (
          <tr>
          <td>{element}</td>
          </tr>
          ))}
          {renderTable(data)}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};
 export default Result;
```

[image: This is my output]
[image: So what I wanted is to be like this]

Comment: The times mentioned on the table (ie, 06:00, 07:00, 01:21, 04:00, 07:21, 08:21, for date 1/2/2022) are not available on your `data` array.

Comment: That is just an example. I want my interface mapped it like the table below.

Comment: So, the numbers will be from the `data` and `hari` arrays - correct? Also, will the elements in both arrays be corresponding to each other? So, first element in `hari` need to match with first element in `data`?

Comment: the time is from the data and the date is from hari.  Both are different arrays. For the data, the array of 0 to 5 will match the first element of the date, 6-11 will match the second element of the date and this will proceed until the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

May be the objective is achievable by changing the `outputList` method like this:

```
const [displayArray, setDisplayArray] = useState([]);
```

.

.

.

```
function outputList() {
  data.length = 0;
  hari.length = 0;
  dObj = {};    // the display object to hold the date & times
  for (let x = 0; x < time.length; x++) {
    for (let z = 0; z < 6; z++) {
      let j = timestamp.toDate(time[x][z]);
      data.push(j.toString().slice(15, 21));
      date.parse(j.toString().slice(4, 15));
      hari.push(date.format("DD/MM/YYYY"));
      const dfmt = date.format("DD/MM/YYYY");
      const dtime = j.toString().slice(15, 21);
      if (dfmt in dObj) {
        dObj[dfmt].concat([dtime]);
      } else {
        dObj[dfmt] = [dfmt, dtime];
      }
    }
  }
  const displayArray = Object.values(dObj);
}
outputList();
```

And, the render may be modified to be something like this:

```
<tbody>({displayArray && displayArray.map((row, rIdx) => (
    <tr key={rIdx}>{
      row.map((elt, eIdx) => (
        <td key={eIdx}>{elt}</td>
      ))
    }</tr>
  ))
})</tbody>
```

NOTE: This is not a full/complete solution; rather, only a concept that may be helpful to achieve the desired objective.